# Excluding a site from combined flair

Tags: support, flair, combined-flair

I have more then 200 reputations on 3 sites

- http://spanish.stackexchange.com
- http://meta.stackexchange.com

and

- http://stackoverflow.com .

All sites are included in the combined flair. I don't want to show my Stack Overflow account on flair.

Is it possible to exclude it from the flair? Thanks!

Comment: In short: no, it's not possible. You can turn this question into a feature request asking to add such a feature.